# Swift2 GeneratorOfOne.next() occur error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

Tags: arrays, swift, generator

I am very confuse about swif2 AnyGenerator and GeneratorOfOne.When I write the following code

```
AnyGenerator(GeneratorOfOne([1,2,3])).next()
```

The compile is correct.
But without use AnyGenerator

```
GeneratorOfOne([1,2,3]).next()
```

The code can't compile.The error is

> cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns
>   immutable value.

Comment: See e.g. [this blog post](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/07/28/collection-and-sequence-helpers/) for some details on `GeneratorOfOne`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the error because `next` is a `mutating` method, which needs to be called on a variable (`var`). Calling it on a constant (`let`) won't work.

This compiles:

```
var generator = GeneratorOfOne([1,2,3])
generator.next()
```

The same `next` call works on `AnyGenerator` because on that struct the method is not a `mutating` one. Se below extracts from the definitions of the two structs in discussion:

```
public struct AnyGenerator<Element> : GeneratorType {

.................................

    public func next() -> Element?
}

public struct GeneratorOfOne<Element> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {

.................................

    public mutating func next() -> Element?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_GeneratorOfOne_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/GeneratorOfOne/s:FVs14GeneratorOfOne4nextFT_GSqx_) `next()` is mutating function. 
You have to keep var reference to it:

```
var generator = GeneratorOfOne([1,2,3])
let next = generator.next()
```